# Send welcome email when user logs in to the app first time

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am developing an android app which is using Google app engine as backend.
I am stuck at a point where i want to send the welcome email to my users when the login into the app for the firs time.

I have googled a lot but did not got proper reference. I followed this official document https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Sending_mail_with_the_JavaMail_API but did not got the result.

So can any one help me out in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ive used both the link you've posted and Sendgrid methods and they both work for me. '
[Sendgrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sendgrid) might be even easier to implement.

```
// set credentials
Sendgrid mail = new Sendgrid("<sendgrid_username>","<sendgrid_password>");

// set email data
mail.setTo("foo@bar.com").setFrom("me@bar.com").setSubject("Subject goes here").setText("Hello World!").setHtml("<strong>Hello World!</strong>");

// send your message
mail.send();
```

What is the exact problem you're having with the other method?

Comment: Yeah this works but i want to implement it using google's email api

Comment: In that case, could you please explain what doesn't work for you with Google's api?